# How to send preflight request from axios of ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, curl, axios

```
curl -s -v --tlsv1.2 -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" -F upfile=@_mat/myfile.mp3 -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS https://api.aicomposer.net:8008/upload
```

There is no `axios.option` thoughm, I made this code.

```
  formData.append(
    "upfile",
    this.state.selectedFile, // _mat/myfile.mp3 is stored from input type="file" here
    this.state.selectedFile.name // 
  );

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "X-Requested-With" ,
      "Access-Control-Request-Method": "POST",
      'Origin':"http://localhost:3000",
    }
  }
  axios.post(`https://api.example.com:8008/upload/`,formData,config).then((res) =>
  {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
  });
```

It shows many errors.....

Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"
Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"

How can I make the equivalent code to `curl`??

---

THank you for comment.

I understood axios send preflight request automatically

However I still not unsure ,how it works.

For example I attached the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to GET request.

```
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  axios.get(`http://api.example.com/upload/`,config).then(res =>{
    console.log("upload endpoint get OK");
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log("upload endpoint get NG");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

It doens't show error but,`upload` connection is called only once in  google developper console.

[image]

Comment: Just make a regular, [non-simple / preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) from the browser... `axios.post(url, formData)`

Comment: Thank you I tried, and found I need to have the way to test if the preflight works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Browser automatically will send preflight requests and cache the response based on the response's cache time.
You can't set such  headers for the sake of security reasons.
Don't worry, the browser will handle them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. but in mycase without testing preflight request by curl` it returns CORS error... when after sending curl request, axios also works.

Comment: @whitebear exactly what _"CORS error"_?

Comment: @Phil `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.net:8008/upload/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` however another request(simple-request) works fine, so I suppose it is preflight problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue... Axios is running locally but the app is on a different port from the server. Axios is not sending an OPTIONS request and then complaining that it didn't get a matching Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. What did you expect, Axios??

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this yesterday and found that it’s a potential bug in v0.27.2 and possibly other versions: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4712. Going to try upgrading to latest today.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33058820)

Answer (score -3):

Axios automatically send preflight OPTIONS request. Check the network tab

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I checked network tab , but the request is sent only once, I want to know how to force `axios` sending OPTIONS explicitly